# Forward fill pandas based on column conditions with increment

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe. I would like to forward fill from the startTime till the endTime for each id I have.

```
id current    startTime  endTime
1  2015-05-10 2015-05-10 2015-05-12
2  2015-07-11 2015-07-11 2015-07-13
3  2015-10-01 2015-10-01 2015-10-03
4  2015-12-01 None       None
```

Here's my expected output:

```
id current    
1  2015-05-10
1  2015-05-11
1  2015-05-12 
2  2015-07-11 
2  2015-07-12 
2  2015-07-13 
3  2015-10-01 
3  2015-10-02 
3  2015-10-03
4  2015-12-01
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `date_range` and `explode` for this.

```
df['current'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['current'] if row['startTime'] is None else pd.date_range(row['startTime'], row['endTime'], freq='D'), axis=1) 

df = df.explode('current')
```

Comment: Yeah, this expands it, thank you! Now how would the explode command work if I have multiple columns I wanted to keep as the current explodes?

Comment: Nvm got it! I can just do newDF= df.explode('current'). Thank you!

Comment: Oh, yeah. Forgot you can explode on dataframe. Your method makes more sense. I am updating my answer.